# Rails: why does simple_token_authentication validate every request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I'm using the simple_token_authentication [gem](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication). I've got it working server-side and I've set the proper authorization headers client-side. While looking at the logs, I've noticed a `User` look-up for every request, which in some situations i.e while using an autocomplete form (which is not on an authenticated page), is not required. The user look-ups look like this:

```
User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2 [["email", "foobar@live.net"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

I must not be understanding the entire concept of how this style of authentication works. What is the intention behind doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Token based authentications are stateless. Every time you want to authenticate, you need to send the token, as Header for example.

So the backend always looks for the token and tries to load the User. Even though your auto complete endpoint doesn't need authentication, but you're probably sending a token with that request. And backend is trying to load a user for that.